# Ligature Symbols not working on Android 2.3

Tags: android, css, cordova, ligature

I've been using http://kudakurage.com/ligature_symbols/ with phonegap. the symbols appear fine on iphone but on Android 2.3 the symbols doesn't appear. 
i.e a heart symbol appears as a word "heart" on Android 2.3.
does anyone know what's the problem?

Comment: are you using the stock font on the device? I don't think it has support for these symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Just include this line in your CSS (in the class where  you define the location of the font):

```
-ms-font-feature-settings:"liga" 1;
```